Linker error: duplicate symbols from libucrt and libmmt, but need both
I'm trying to build a project with the Intel OneAPI 2024.2.1 compiler.
My 32-bit release build has the issue of multiply defined symbols.
There's a few math functions that are causing problems:
lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __CIcos
>>> defined at libmmt.lib(cos_iface_c99.obj)
>>> defined at libucrt.lib(cos_impl.obj)

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __CIexp
>>> defined at libmmt.lib(exp_iface_c99.obj)
>>> defined at libucrt.lib(87ctran.obj)

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __CIlog
>>> defined at libmmt.lib(log_iface_c99.obj)
>>> defined at libucrt.lib(log_impl.obj)

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __CIpow
>>> defined at libmmt.lib(pow_iface_c99.obj)
>>> defined at libucrt.lib(pow_impl.obj)

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __CIsin
>>> defined at libmmt.lib(sin_iface_c99.obj)
>>> defined at libucrt.lib(sin_impl.obj)

lld-link: error: duplicate symbol: __CItan
>>> defined at libmmt.lib(tan_iface_c99.obj)
>>> defined at libucrt.lib(tan_impl.obj)

The big problem is, when I exclude either of these libraries (using /nodefaultlib) I get a bunch of missing implementations.
I read something somewhere about stripping some objects out of libucrt, but that's the very last thing I want to be doing. And I can't imagine that's really necessary: there's no way I'm the very first person to try and build a 32 bit release build.
What am I missing here?
Bit more context:
I'm trying to use CMakeLists to stitch together multiple libraries. I'm setting /MT (and replacing /MD) on everything I've made myself, but there's a lot I'm pulling from git repos. However, I'm not getting any warnings about static/dynamic linking mismatch. So I'm assuming the linker errors I'm getting now aren't due to "mixing runtimes" (correct me if I'm wrong, my knowledge on this is very basic).

You can't mix runtimes in a single executable, you'll need to compile all your libraries with the same runtime

I'm not mixing runtimes. What makes you think that?

Well you've given us very little information to work with but these kind of errors are always due to incompatible runtimes, where that's coming from I've no idea but I'm pretty sure that'll be the issue

What do you mean by incompatible runtimes exactly? Like /MT versus /MD? Or is libmmt from another runtime as libucrt? How would I have caused such a problem? You're giving me very little information to work with.

I did ask some very specific questions you could just take the time to answer, instead of taking that same time to make an unhelpful, condescending comment.

Ok, I'll stop trying to help if my help isn't wanted

libucrt.lib is one of the "standard" runtimes for Visual Studio. Among other things, it implements math functions. libmmt.lib is a math library of Intel compiler. They cannot co-exist in a single executable.

@Tsyvarev libucrt.lib is the static Universal CRT library. That is part of the OS, not Visual Studio. The remainder of your comment is correct, though.

Ok, so I was understanding correctly, except for the part where they cannot co-exist in one executable. If I nodefaultlib libucrt, all hell breaks loose, and if I nodefaultlib libmmt, I'm missing a bunch of math functions. Anyone who uses sin or cos in their project would bump into the same problem then, right?

@T.J.Evers: You cannot link a single executable using both libucrt.lib and libmmt.lib. If your project has one part (e.g. library) which is compiled for libucrt.lib and some another part which is compiled for libmmt.lib, then those parts cannot be linked into the single executable. You need to re-design your project to use only parts (libraries) compiled for the same runtime.
